Recomposition when lambda vs function reference passed as parameter
I have the following TestViewModel which will continuously refresh any composable which collects from it.
(specifically: timeFlow is being updated by a count-down timer, and the composable collects it as state)
class TestViewModel(
    timeSeconds: Int,
): ViewModel() {

    private val _timeState = MutableStateFlow(value = 0L)
    val timeFlow = _timeState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        // initial time and tick interval
        object : CountDownTimer(timeSeconds * 1000L, 1000L) {
            override fun onTick(timeLeft: Long) = _timeState.update { timeLeft }
            override fun onFinish() = onTick(timeLeft = 0L)
        }.start() // start immediately
    }
}

My TestScreen collects the time from the viewModel into timeState (this causes frequent recomposition as timeFlow is being updated), and displays it onto the screen. Additionally, some state is remembered, and some actions are provided to change that state when a Button is pressed.
@Composable
fun TestScreen(
    viewModel: TestViewModel,
) {
    val timeState = viewModel.timeFlow.collectAsState()

    var state by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    // two actions which change the state
    fun func() { state = !state }
    val lambda = { state = !state }

    // ui stuff so that the example looks nicer
    Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding).fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(24.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
            Text("Time: ${timeState.value}")
            Text("State: $state")
            Button(     // <--- the Button which calls one of the actions
                onClick = ::func,          // pass function by reference, recompose!
                // onClick = { func() },   // call function inside of lambda, skip!
                // onClick = lambda,       // pass lambda by reference, skip!
                // onClick = { lambda() }, // call lambda inside of lambda, skip!
            ) {
                Text("Change State")
            }
        }
    }
}

When the func is used as a function reference, the whole button is recomposed at every TestScreen recomposition, even though func is stable, it does not seem to change between recompositions.
However, in the other three cases the button recomposition is skipped.
Note that it doesn't have to be a button, any composable to which a function is passed as a reference will be similarly recomposed.
The constant recomposition of the button seems like a waste of resources (especially when the timer ticks faster than once per second), and I would like to eliminate it. My actual use-case is a timer app with many clickable icons, each of which is recomposed (redrawn) at every tick of the timer.
It seems that defining a function (func()) inside another function (TestScreen()) is different than defining a lambda and storing it in a val. I would like an explanation as to why this might be the case, and a recommendation as to which approach is better both performance-wise and code-style-wise.

I've never used method reference in Kotlin,
I tried your code and confirm that the issue source is at passing function reference, this is my guess,

With every recomposition, a new reference might be created (as we use "remember" keyword to retain a value across recompositions) and therefore recomposition of the Button

as you also asked about coding practices or approach

Local function is fine for executing a code block which is supposed to be local
I've never seen the use of function reference in Compose, it's all states and events.
Also I recommend shifting the code inside Scaffold in a Composable and updating the state using events.
You can further separate the code into Stateful and Stateless Composable

